# using the LOCATION_SERVICE from a Thread

Tags: java, android

How can I use the LOCATION_SERVICE from the run() method of a class that extends Thread?
Both of these are giving me errors:

```
lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type Thread_ReadGps and

```
lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

LOCATION_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

getSystemService is a method of context, so you need to call it like you are in your second line.

LOCATION_SERVICE is a static variable of context as well, so you need to call it like in your first line. So just combine your first and second lines to get:

```
lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: It makes sense now, Thank you!