# using getsystemservice function outside activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to use getSystemService in a non-Activity class but when i do I get some error. here is the code below:

```
double latitude,longitude;
android.location.Location l;
static LocationManager lm;
Toast.makeText(context, "Before", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
latitude= l.getLatitude();
longitude = l.getLongitude();

String po="after";
Toast.makeText(context, po1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I do not want to use any other activity class. Any help would be appreciated. All this work is done in a non activity class method. here is the full code of broadcast reciever

```
public class SMSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

android.location.Location l;
static LocationManager lm;
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "";
double lat,lng;
String request,ipaddress="",originatingno;

public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Parse the SMS.
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if(bundle != null)
    {
        // Retrieve the SMS.
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            request=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            ipaddress=request.substring(4);
            originatingno= msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();


        }
        if(request.startsWith("fr"))
        {


            sabkuch db =new sabkuch(context); 
            db.open();
            long id = db.insertContact(originatingno,"shubh");
            db.close();

        }
        if(request.startsWith("lr"))
        {
            double latitude,longitude;
             Toast.makeText(context, "Before", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
              //String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
             l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            latitude= l.getLatitude();
             longitude = l.getLongitude();

             String po="Shubham's location: " +
                    " Latitude: "+String.valueOf(latitude)+
                    " Longitude: "+String.valueOf(longitude);

           Toast.makeText(context, po, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }


    }}
```

}

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870667/how-can-i-use-getsystemservice-in-a-non-activity-class-locationmanager

Comment: send the context of calling activity to the constructor of the non Activity class

Answer (score 0):

Try this from `Activity` send `Context` to non activity class and with that `context` you can use `getSystemService`.

```
lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

### EDIT :

```
public class SMSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

android.location.Location l;
LocationManager lm;
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "";
double lat,lng;
String request,ipaddress="",originatingno;

public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Parse the SMS.
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    if(bundle != null)
    {
        // Retrieve the SMS.
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
            request=msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            ipaddress=request.substring(4);
            originatingno= msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();


        }
        if(request.startsWith("fr"))
        {


            sabkuch db =new sabkuch(context); 
            db.open();
            long id = db.insertContact(originatingno,"shubh");
            db.close();

        }
        if(request.startsWith("lr"))
        {
            double latitude,longitude;
             Toast.makeText(context, "Before", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
              //String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
             l = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            latitude= l.getLatitude();
             longitude = l.getLongitude();

             String po="Shubham's location: " +
                    " Latitude: "+String.valueOf(latitude)+
                    " Longitude: "+String.valueOf(longitude);

           Toast.makeText(context, po, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not using activity. Actually I am using a broadcast reciever which i have made inside a non activity class, so whenever a message will arrive it will generate the location of the phone and send it back. So  how to send context??

Comment: In the BroadcastReceiver's public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) method you can use the context parameter to access the system services like described by kaushik. In utility classes, that need to access system services you should pass the Context object (the Activity itself via this) as a method or constructor parameter.

Comment: @shubham : u have used `context` to show `Toast`. So, use the same `context` for `getSystemService`. In `BroadcastReceiver's` `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` u'll get the `context` as [**ptk93**](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3649498/ptk93) mentioned.

Comment: when i use that context it shows LOCATION_SERVICE cannot be resolved to a variable.. And when i use lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); it does not show error there but when i receive some message it shows null pointer exception in logcat

Comment: lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(`context`.LOCATION_SERVICE); instead use lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(`Context`.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Comment: @kaushik do something buddy its my project i have to submit

Comment: don't know what happened.But what I have written as answer that works for me. try to  copy that line from my answer and replace that in your code.

Comment: can u send me your code means full code so that I could take some hint

Comment: @shubham : you can take a look at [using the LOCATION_SERVICE from a Thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914170/using-the-location-service-from-a-thread)